# Automatic refresh of Google Maps Markers

Tags: javascript, mysql, google-maps-api-3

i hope you can help me with my following problem. since days I´m tinkering on it, but it won´t run...

I´m writing a little web-app based on Google Maps API on wich i can mark my actual position on a map with a modified marker-symbol an so on. Everything works great so far. I receive my geolocation via HTML5-Geolocation function and write the values in to a mysql database. In a separate function (see below) i read out this data an set the marker with my modified symbol on the map.

The next I wan´t to solve is to remove the marker after about 40 minutes automatically from the map. For this I created a separate table on my database which gets filled with the marker-information from the main table. This works so far, I solved it with a php-script and a cron-job. Then the entry from the main table becomes deleted. What makes me insane is to remove the marker after the 40 minutes from the map. I tried several things, from creating arrays with the data of the "to-remove-table", i played around with the setMap-function of Google Maps API, but I´m still on the line.

Here is my code where I read out the data from database and set the marker on the map:

```
function markPolitesse() {

  var infoWindow_spotted = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

  downloadUrl("phpsqlajax_genxml2.php", function(data) {

  var xml = data.responseXML;
  var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("politesse_spotted");

  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var number = markers[i].getAttribute("number");
    var city = markers[i].getAttribute("city");
    var zipcode = markers[i].getAttribute("zipcode");
    var street = markers[i].getAttribute("street");
    var type = markers[i].getAttribute("street");
    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
      parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
      parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
    var html = "<b>" + city + "</b> <br/>" + zipcode + "</b> <br/>" + type + "</b> <br/>";    

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        title: number,
        icon: politessenImage
      });

    bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow_spotted, html);
     }
  });
}
```

The main- and the "remove-table" contain the following fields:
number, city, zipcode, street, streetnumber, coordinates_lat, coordinates_lng, time, date

I hope you have a impulse for me I would be thankful...

Regards,
Stefan

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Do you want the map to refresh automatically without having to reload the page? Or are you saying that even if you refresh the page you see the marker in the old position?

Comment: When I refresh the page everything is fine. But i don´t want to reload the whole page all the time. Of course, bedding it into a div or iframe that get´s refreshed would work, but i I think when i can add a marker without a reload I can also reload it without a refresh. When there is no other way it´s okay, but I think building a construction around "setMap" could solve it in an elegant way...But it´s only a thought!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the marker in a global variable/outside the function, then in your function do the following:

```
marker.setMap(null);
// set up new marker
```

Then assign your new marker.

Comment: This is a good and simple idea! But what when I have more markers (for example 5), and I delete only one? With this solution, all existing markers become deleted (the one I want to delete and the 4 other existing) and and only one new is set on my actual location. The other "old" four ones are still in the database but don´t appear anymore on the map... Playing around a little, maybe one of you has another impulse...

Comment: Ok, I finally solved it! Putting it into an array and working with that was the key... Thank you all!